# show only 5 thumbnails pictures of a gallery

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am looking for a solution to show only the first 5 thumbnails pictures of a gallery.

Right now I have a big picture and beneath it all pictures as thumbnails.
Clicking on the thumbnail will open a popup gallery slideshow.

I want to limit the visible thumbnail pictures on the page to max 5 and hide the others.

Does anybody know a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'd generally suggest with code. For something more specific, can you provide some of your relevant code to give us a chance to help edge you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide some of your code so we can help you the best.
but the simple way to do it by: `overflow: hidden;` with specific `width`
example:

```
.thumbnails
{
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

.thumbnail 
{
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

elements with class `.thumbnails` will hold the images and each image will have a class of `.thumbnail`

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/277tdp0y/1/